# Cross Page Posting not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, cross-page-posting

I am trying to pass the value of a variable from one page to another using cross page post-back using this code:

on page1:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="changepwd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="ChangePassword" runat="server" Text="Change Password" 
 PostBackUrl="~/Page2.aspx" />
```

I have assigned its value at runtime from the database in the cs file as:
 `changepwd.Text = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["empPassword"].ToString();`

On page 2:
 In page load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PreviousPage != null && PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack)
        {
            TextBox txt = (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("changepwd");
            TextBox1.Text = txt.Text;
        }
    }
```

but I don't get the value from the previous page. i am getting the value as `null`.
On page1 I am getting the value correctly from the database but it is not being passed onto page 2. Can you please tell me why?

Comment: Is your textbox directly within page 1's naming container, or within some other control on the page? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139(v=vs.100).aspx) says: 
*The FindControl method finds controls in the current naming container. If the control you are looking for is inside another control (typically, inside a template), you must first get a reference to the container and then search the container to find the control you want to get.*

Comment: no it is not within any other control

Comment: are you using master pages?

Comment: Expose the textbox's text as a public property of page 1, then in page 2, cast PreviousPage to page 1's type and read the property.

Comment: nope.. im not using master page

Answer (score 0):

Hope its helping u:

Page 1:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="changepwd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="btnChangePassword" runat="server" Text="Change Password" 
 PostBackUrl="~/Page2.aspx" />
```

Page 1 Behind Code:

```
public TextBox ChangePassword
{
    get
    {
        return changepwd;
    }
}
```

Page 2: 
define this at the page header:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Page1.aspx" %>
```

Page 2 Behind Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.PreviousPage != null && PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack == true)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = PreviousPage.ChangePassword.Text;
    }
}
```